# User profile service issues

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, powershell

I had this question earlier but did not find any solution. My user profile service synchronization is not starting. I tried stopping the service and restarted it also but no luck. Is deleting the user profile service and recreating a better solution. Please advise.

Comment: Did you tried to stop using powershell command?

Comment: Yes, I stopped and restarted after which it did not start at all

Answer (score 0):

its depend whats going on.You have to check the following things.

- when you start the sync service, make farm admin account should be in local admin on server
- make sure Timer and Admin service running on server
- Check the event log for clue

Comment: The sync service is running in the local admin. It was running well until i stopped the service and restarted it. After that now the User Profile service shows as Provision in powershell instead on Online

Comment: One thing is my User Profile Service Application - User Profile Incremental Synchronization  failes everyday

Comment: you have to see the logs why it is failing, may be sync connection to Ad having the issue...i think account how is configure for the import may be dont have permission or bad password or account locked

Comment: how do i check if it does not have permission or bad password or account locked. Does it have anything to do with User profile synchronization also.

Comment: Uls logs and event logs will give you the clue. this is connection account which bring the data from ad into sharepoint

Comment: I think I have looked into the event log earlier and through which i followed fixing the error and it said to stop the user profile service and restart the service after which the User profile service synchronization is showing as starting

Comment: Do you think delete the user profile service application and recreating new again should fix this problem

Comment: again, its depend upon the error, if you share the error may be we can help...

Comment: event id : 6313    The server encountered an unexpected error creating performance counters for management agent "MOSSAD-nha.org".
 Performance counters will not be available for this management agent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36139/discussion-on-answer-by-waqas-sarwar-mcse-user-profile-service-issues).